# how to do a Responsive images in a list with inline-block

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4, responsive-images

so my problem is that i have 3 images with uneven width and still make them intact until it hit a certain width let's say 767px. and when it hit that width each of the images will take a full width of 767px until xs size of screen. sorry if this sentence construction make you crazy.

here's a piece

```
<div class= "about-content">

                    <ul>

                        <li><a href="">
                            <div class = "inner-content">

                                <img src="img/about/1.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                            </div>


                                </a></li><li><a href="">
                                <div class = "inner-content">
                                    <img src="img/about/2.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                                        <div class = "overlay-content">
                                            <h4>Book a Test Drive <i class = "fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></h4>                                 
                                        </div>
                                </div>


                                </a></li><li><a href=""><img src="img/about/3.jpg" class="img-fluid"></a></li>

                    </ul>
                    <ul>

                                <li><a href=""><img src="img/about/4.jpg">

                                </a></li><li><a href=""><img src="img/about/5.jpg">

                                </a></li><li><a href=""><img src="img/about/6.jpg"></a></li>

                    </ul>

                </div>
```

Comment: I think, if I understand your question, you need to look into <a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries">Media Queries</a> which will allow you to change styles based on screen width (and other things).

Comment: yeah. i tried that. it was responsive tho. but it's not resizing the full width . it remains at full width of the image. not increase its width. losing quality is okay i just want to play with it. and see what i can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images will expand if you use `vw` (viewport width) measurement. Set a calculation to compensate for their starting positioning as in `width: calc(100vw - 70px)`

Here's a snippet:

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 767px) {
  img {
    width: calc(100vw - 70px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="about-content">

  <ul>

    <li>
      <a href="">
        <div class="inner-content">

          <img src="img/about/1.jpg" class="img-fluid">
        </div>


      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">
        <div class="inner-content">
          <img src="img/about/2.jpg" class="img-fluid">
          <div class="overlay-content">
            <h4>Book a Test Drive <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></h4>
          </div>
        </div>


      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href=""><img src="img/about/3.jpg" class="img-fluid"></a>
    </li>

  </ul>
  <ul>

    <li>
      <a href=""><img src="img/about/4.jpg">

      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href=""><img src="img/about/5.jpg">

      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href=""><img src="img/about/6.jpg"></a>
    </li>

  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: thank you , i got it now. time to play with it. so thats how you do it. lastly is this supported by all of the browsers??

Comment: You're welcome. That's one of possibly other ways to do it. Javascript is another route. For compatibility, you can check [https://caniuse.com/#search=calc](https://caniuse.com/#search=calc). Generally looks good except for IE10 and below. js will be more compatible.

Answer (score 0):

A way to globally give all images a responsive width is to just write this in your css file or inline style in the body tag:

```
<body style="img{width:100%;height:auto;}">
```

other way in the css file is:

```
img
{
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
```

You can also change the `%` to lower as well just play around with the percent until u get it how you need it.

Ideally you should also read about [@media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Comment: i do have that. in my css code. what i want is when i hit that px. it should cover a the whole space. what happening was when it hit a <li > it comes down . then the normal size of the images will remain. i want the images when it hit the <li> the 3 images will cover the full width like to be resize 767px it's okay if i lose some quality in those images i just want to learn how to do that so i can play with it